# Serialization in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

I am using `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer` in my ASP.NET Web API project and have a return object defined as

**Response Object**

```
public class MyResponse 
{
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public CustomField<string> Username {get;set;}

   public CustomField<float?> Score {get;set;}
}
```

**Custom Field**

```
public class CustomField<T>
{
    public T Value {get;set;}

    public long LastModified {get;set;}

}
```

I want to generate an XML response as

```
<MyResponse>
 <FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
 <Username lastModified="1234">XYZ</Username>
 <Score lastModified="45678">12002</Score>
</MyResponse>
```

ASP.NET Web API returns a JSON object (I am aware that this happens when XmlSerialization does not work correctly) when I decorate the `CustomField` class as

```
public class CustomField<T>
{
    [XmlText]
    public T Value {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public long LastModified {get;set;}
}
```

How can I get the desired XML response ?

Comment: This might help you track down the problem http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2012/08/10/troubleshooting-serialization-problems-in-web-api/

Comment: Just checking, do you have an Accept header on your request for XML? JSON is the default format if no particular content-type is asked for by the request.

Comment: Yes sir. I do have the correct headers

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I know what's going on.

If you try to run

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyResponse))
```

you'll get this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize member 'Value' of type System.Nullable`1[System.Single]. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.

So the issue is that you have a field of type 'float?' as an [XmlText]. [XmlText] can only be applied to primitives, and it doesn't look like XmlSerializer recognizes 'float?' as a primitive. If you use 'float' instead of 'float?', everything looks to be working right. If you want to indicate that sometimes there is no Score, you may want to set the Score to null instead of the Score's value to null.

Hope that helps.